# Generate random numeric & alphabetic

Tags: string, random, hex, generator, basic

I'm making a random hexadecimal generator is it possible in visual basic to make a code that randomly generates number and letters together? How would you do it? I'm really lost. I'd like to randomly generate a 2 string hexadecimal including numbers and letters or sometimes output just either a letter or a string.

I'd like to randomly generate for example "01", "A" , "AF", "B2", "8", "0F" etc

Comment: Why produce random text? Just produce random bits and then convert them to text.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random integer (as the usual base 10) using `System.Random`, and then convert the Base 10 integer into a Base 16 string reasonably easily:

```
Convert.ToString(myNumber, 16)
```

Comment: MSDN information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an algorithm that first got a random number 1 (1 for the values such as "8")or 2 (0 or 1 if index starts at 0 (i haven't done BASIC in a while)). Then generate a random index from a list. Put them together and you got your string.